# single template object for multiple data types

Tags: c++, templates

```
class mypair {
    T a, b;
  public:
    mypair (T first, T second)
      {a=first; b=second;}
    T getmax ();
};

template <class T>
T mypair<T>::getmax ()
{
  T retval;
  retval = a>b? a : b;
  return retval;
}

int main () {
  int i;
  cin>>i;
  if(i==0)
      mypair <int> myobject (100, 75);
  else
      mypair <float> myobject (100, 75);

  cout << myobject.getmax();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to create a single object of my template class based on the value of i. if the value of i is 0, then create a template class of data type int else float. 
the above program throws an error ‘myobject’ was not declared in this scope in the 2nd last line where I call the getmax function.

How can I achieve that>

Comment: Also myobject Only has scope in the if else block. Declare it above and have it get aassignedin the if else block

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun But to declare it before `if` we need 'type' information and we need `i` to determine the type

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a function template to do the work?

```
template <typename T>
doStuff()
{
  mypair <T> myobject (100, 75);
  std::cout << myobject.getmax();
}
```

then

```
if(i==0)
  doStuff<int>();
else
  doStuff<float>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is scope:

```
if(i==0)
{
      mypair <int> myobject (100, 75);
} // myobject is now out of scope and unusable
  else
{
      mypair <float> myobject (100, 75);
}  // myobject is now out of scope and unusable
```

You will need to declare a nontemplate base for the template
And then you can declare a pointer to the base
do a new in your if clause
then you can use the pointer in the code below

As an aside, its generally helpful to always include {} even for single line blocks

Answer (score 0):

It's because of scope of the if and else case..
You can acheive this by doing like this

```
if(i==0){
  mypair <int> myobject (100, 75);
  cout << myobject.getmax();
} 
else{
  mypair <float> myobject (100, 75);
  cout << myobject.getmax();
}
```

Since the object is alive within the scope of if and else scope outside it will be dead.

```
if{
     // alive scope
 }
 //dead scope
```